# CakePhp 3 menu com dados do banco de dados

Tags: cakephp-3

Estou começando no CakePHP, usando a versão 3.
Estou desenvolvendo um blog, eu preciso inserir no layout um menu com os dados do banco de dados. (Tabela categorias) Ex: CategoryA | categoria | ... | Categoria
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Utilize um novo recurso do cakephp 3, View Cells: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html.